# Why SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error?

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is a code to register the head of a group and then his partner(s).

```
<?
session_start();
require_once('db.php');
$db = new DB();
$db->newHead($_POST['fname'], $_POST['lname'], $_POST['school'], $_POST['day'], $_POST['month'], $_POST['year'], $_POST['email']);
$hId = $db->getId($_POST['email'], 1);
if ($_POST['pnum'] === 1)
{
    $db->newPartner($hId, $_POST['fname1'], $_POST['lname1'], $_POST['day1'], $_POST['month1'], $POST['year1'], $_POST['email1']);
    $pId = getId($_POST['email1'], 0);
    $db->setHeadId($hId, $pId, 1);
}
if ($_POST['pnum'] === 2)
{
    $db->newPartner($hId, $_POST['fname1'], $_POST['lname1'], $_POST['day1'], $_POST['month1'], $POST['year1'], $_POST['email1']);
    $p1Id = getId($_POST['email1'], 0);
    $db->setHeadId($hId, $p1Id, 1);

    $db->newPartner($hId, $_POST['fname2'], $_POST['lname2'], $_POST['day2'], $_POST['month2'], $POST['year2'], $_POST['email2']);
    $p2Id = getId($_POST['email2'], 0);
    $db->setHeadId($hId, $p2Id, 2);
}
header("Location:Register.php");
?>
```

and this is part of db.php:

```
    public function getId($email, $type)
{
    if ($type)
        $query = "SELECT * FROM t_head where h_email = '$email';";
    else
        $query = "SELECT * FROM t_partner where p_email = '$email';";
    return $this->query($query);
}

public function newPartner($hId, $fname, $lname, $day, $month, $year, $email)
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO t_partner (p_headid, p_fname, p_lname, p_day, p_month, p_year, p_email)
    VALUES ('$hId', '$fname', '$lname', '$day', '$month', '$year', '$email');";
    return $this->query($query);
}

public function newHead($fname, $lname, $hschool, $day, $month, $year, $email)
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO t_head (h_fname, h_lname, h_school, h_day, h_month, h_year, h_email)
    VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$hschool', '$day', '$month', '$year', '$email');";
    return $this->query($query);
}

    public function setHeadId($hId, $pId, $num)
    {
        if ($num === 1)
            $query = "UPDATE t_head SET h_p1 = '$pId' WHERE h_id = '$hId';";
        else
            $query = "UPDATE t_head SET h_p2 = '$pId' WHERE h_id = '$hId';";
        $this->execute($query);
    }
```

What's the problem?
DB is class that is worked with PDO. (I don't know what's this! but I always copy it then I write the functions at then bottom of it and it always worked correctly.) But know What does this error mean?

- Excuse me If I pasted all of the code! I don't know `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error` is related to which part, so that I couldn't paste any specific part/func for you.
- My site copied to another server and the DNS was changed near 3 hours ago for a purpose. If this detail can help you ...

Comment: what's the full (mysql) error message?

Comment: The problem is that the message is only this short error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: do you have a stored procedure? http://www.joeyrivera.com/2009/sqlstatehy000-general-error-using-phppdo-mysql-stored-procedures-sp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened to me something similar a few weeks ago. I fixed it changing the php.ini

I changed

```
;extension=php_pdo_mysql_mysqlnd.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql_libmysql.dll
```

to

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql_mysqlnd.dll
;extension=php_pdo_mysql_libmysql.dll
```

basically you change the mysql driver php uses. I used xampplite 1.7

Comment: Be sure to restart the server when making changes to php.ini

Comment: There is a big problem! My host is not my own server(Not a distinct server! Share server!)! So I think I don't have any access to php.ini.

Comment: You could take a look at this if you decide to go along these lines.. http://uk3.php.net/dl

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work:
`if (!extension_loaded('php_pdo_mysql_mysqlnd')) {
        dl('php_pdo_mysql_mysqlnd.dll');
}
if (!extension_loaded('php_pdo_mysql_libmysql')) {
        dl('php_pdo_mysql_libmysql.dll');
}`