# PDO error uncaught exception SQLSTATE[HY000]

Tags: php, pdo

I keep getting this error but i don't know why....

The error is:

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]:

General error' in test.php:25\nStack trace:\n#0 test.php(25): 

PDOStatement->fetch()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in test.php on line 25
```

My query is like this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("

SELECT *,t1.id AS theID FROM users
   t1 LEFT JOIN users_settings t2
ON t1.id=t2.tid                 
   INNER JOIN extra_settings t3
ON t2.bid=t3.id");

try {
    $stmt->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e -> getMessage();  
}

while($row = $stmt->fetch()){ //error is here
    //do stuff
}
```

The script works but the error displays anyway =/

What does the error mean and how do i fix it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why SQLSTATE\[HY000\]: General error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199571/why-sqlstatehy000-general-error)

Comment: The answer there did not solve my problem so not really a duplicate.

Comment: @Dave Just to double check, the query gives the correct result if entered at a SQL prompt, and the `execute()` does not give any error output to the page?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson No error on my screen, i removed the query and did a basic `select * from table` and it worked fine, so my guess its to do with my joins ?

Comment: @Dave As long as the query runs at an SQL prompt, it should run fine in PDO. Do you have any queries before this one in the page?

Comment: No its the first query in the script, it does execute - my database updates but I get that error anyway.

Comment: What if you change your query to simple `"SELECT 1;"` and try again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have to run the while loop within the `try` statement:

```
try {
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        //do stuff
    }
} 
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e -> getMessage();  
}
```

You are seeing this message because there is something wrong with your query. Try:

```
SELECT *,t1.id AS theID FROM users
   t1 LEFT JOIN t2.users_settings
   ON t1.id=t2.tid                 
   INNER JOIN t3.extra_settings
   ON t2.bid=t3.id
```

Comment: I don't think thats the case i've never seen it being placed inside the `try` statement in the php manual.

Comment: It would not solve your issue, but it will prevent the `Uncaught exception` message, see my update

Comment: Hmmm... could it be your query?

Comment: Ill do a test query  of a simple select please hold.

Comment: @Dave If you get `Uncaught exception`s then it simply means that you are not catching the exception. Put **everything** inside `try...catch` blocks and then `var_dump($e->getMessage());die;`. It will show you what the problem is.

Comment: I just did a simple select statement: `$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");`

Worked perfectly fine. So it must be something to do with a left join and inner join =/

Comment: In that case it's definitely your query.

Comment: maybe change `users_settings t2` to `t2.users_settings` and `extra_settings t3` to `t3.extra_settings`?

Comment: I'm thinking maybe the left join tied to an inner join is not allowed =/

Comment: `Uncaught exception` error is not relevant to the problem. The meaningful part is `General error`. So, this is not the answer but rather a comment

Comment: Hmm general error doesn't help tell me the mistake :( im guessing its a logic error ?